# R: Combining Merges and Fuzzy Merges in Single Statement

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working with the R programming language.

I have the following two tables:

```r
library(stringdist)
    
table1 <- data.frame(col1_a = c("appple", "orangesz", "banana", "pear"), col2_a = c(123, 456, 789, 234))
table2 <- data.frame(col1_b = c("aples", "orange", "bannnana", "pear"), col2_b = c(123, 456, 789, 567))
```

I am trying to merge these two tables on the following two conditions:

- if col2_a = col2_b
- if col1_a and col2_a have a "levenstein distance" of less than 5

I tried to do this in 2 steps:

First, I defined a function to calculate the levenstein distance:

```r
is_close_enough <- function(s1, s2) {
   stringdist(s1, s2) < 5
}
```

Then, I tried the join:

```r
library(dplyr)
result <- merge(table1, table2, by = NULL) %>%
    filter(is_close_enough(table1$col1_a, table2$col1_b), table1$col2_a == table2$col2_b)
```

But I got the following error:

```
Error in `filter()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = is_close_enough(table1$col1_a, table2$col1_b)`.
x Input `..1` must be of size 16 or 1, not size 4.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Can someone please show me how to fix this error?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't use `table1$` or `table2$` in your `filter()` command, that would refer to the unmerged values. Just use the column names as variables. Also if you are using the latest version of `dplyr`, use `inner_join()` with `join_by()` rather than using the base R `merge()`

Comment: Try this: `merge(table1, table2, by = NULL) %>%
    mutate(close_enough = is_close_enough(col1_a, col1_b)) %>%
    filter(close_enough)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
library(stringdist)
library(dplyr)
is_close_enough <- function(s1, s2) {
  stringdist(s1, s2) < 5
}

table1 <- data.frame(col1_a = c("appple", "orangesz", "banana", "pear"), col2_a = c(123, 456, 789, 234))
table2 <- data.frame(col1_b = c("aples", "orange", "bannnana", "pear"), col2_b = c(123, 456, 789, 567))

# Using cross join is more intuitive than merge
dplyr::cross_join(table1, table2) %>% 
  filter(
    is_close_enough(col1_a, col1_b),
    col2_a == col2_b
    )
#>     col1_a col2_a   col1_b col2_b
#> 1   appple    123    aples    123
#> 2 orangesz    456   orange    456
#> 3   banana    789 bannnana    789
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

You have to remove the `$` in filter()` https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/filter.html for more filter examples